# ¿Cómo realizar este tipo Slide Vertical? En Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, unity

Estoy tratando de hacer una app y deseo incorporarle un splash screen. Cansado de tener splash screen estáticas estoy pensando en hacer una que he visto en la app de root "KingRoot" pero no sé el nombre ni donde buscar información sobre ella.

Se trata como si fuera una misma imagen en vertical pero que ocupara 3 pantallas verticales, es decir, deslizas con el dedo y vas bajando, la pantalla que está va desapareciendo a la vez que bajas y aparece la siguiente pantalla, y así con la tercera también. Me gustaría saber el nombre para poder buscar información sobre ella o si nativamente en C# o Java.

EDITADO:

Código para realizar Slide horizontal y con profundidad pero mi necesidad es convertirlo a Slide VERTICAL y quitarle esa profuncidad:

`public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager2.PageTransformer {`

```
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0f);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1f);
        view.setTranslationX(0f);
        view.setScaleX(1f);
        view.setScaleY(1f);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1 - position);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0f);
    }
}}
```

Debo cambiar la "X" por "Y" ?

Comment: Por la descripción parece el componente Carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se exactamente lo que quieres pero se lee como un Slide entre fragments

Según Google se puede crear de esta forma:

Creamos el xml de la activity:

```
<!-- fragment_screen_slide_page.xml -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
</ScrollView>
```

Creamos el fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Añadimos un ViewPager:

```
<!-- activity_screen_slide.xml -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Y por ultimo el archivo Java de la activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
...
public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/**
 * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
 */
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to 
 access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to 
handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

Nunca lo e utilizado pero me imagino que aquí todos aprendemos juntos n.n

Te dejo la documentación ya que tiene un par de transiciones interesantes al final de la pagina.

Espero te sirva, igual haré unas pruebas, se ve muy bien para las aplicaciones.

[Documentación sobre Slide entre fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide#java)

Comment: Hola Artudoxo, gracias por tu contribución, cuando no estemos seguros de lo que se pregunta hay que requerir más información para poder ayudar al usuario de otra forma tal vez lo que respondas no sea lo correcto, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Hola Artudoxo, muchas gracias, ese es el camino de mi pregunta, es un Slide, pero no me salía el nombre. Al llegar a casa revisare si funciona pues conseguí hacer un Slide de arriba hacia abajo pero mediante botón, por tanto es un "Slide falso" ya que necesito tal cual con el dedo deslizar hacia abajo mientras se "apaga" y vuelve transparente la parte de arriba. Probaré y te comento, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, he revisado cómo en Google te dice como hacer el "depth page trasnformer" que es el slide que necesito pero en vez de ser horizontal, debe ser en vertical y sin profundidad , unicamente deslizar hacia abajo y ya está. He actualizado en la pregunta con el código que Google dice que se hace pero si necesito los cambios que comento, únicamente tengo que cambiar "X" por "Y" y quitarle algun factor para que en la transicion quite esa profundidad?

Comment: Bueno en cuanto a la profundidad, en esta ocasión si no sabría como ayudarte, nunca he intentado quitarle la profundidad y si, en cuanto a la orientación debería funcionar como mencionas.